# C++ casting oddness

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's use this simple class hierarchy:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Af() {};
};

class IB
{
public:
    virtual void Bf() = 0;
};

class C : public A, public IB
{
public:
    virtual void Bf() {}
    void Cf() { printf("Cf"); }
};
```

An now some tests I have done, trying to understand static_cast and dynamic_cast:

```
1) C* c = new C();
2) A* a = static_cast<A*>(c);
3) IB* ib = static_cast<IB*>(c); //ib gets a different pointer than c because ib vtable is assigned 
4) A* correctA = static_cast<A*>(static_cast<C*>(ib)); //Correct, but I must cast first to C and the to A from Interface
5) A* incorrectA = static_cast<A*>(ib); //Compiler error
6) A* correctA2 = dynamic_cast<A*>(ib); //Correct result
```

Now, some questions:

1) I have started to code in C++ since I moved to C# about 5 years ago. I'm surprised of the "ib" variable value in number 3. I expected it to be same pointer as "c" variable but instead the cast is assigning the value of the vtable of class "ib" in "c"

2) Why must I cast fist to C* and then to A* in 3 to get a correct value? This makes polimorphism useless in this case. Because I want to cast from the interface to the base type without knowing the real type. 5 shows that this is not possible with static_cast (I guess that this is checking the inheritance tree and concluding IB interface is not related to A* but they really are at runtime.

3) 6 gets a correct value into correctA2. I guess it does this correclty as I explain in question 2 because this can be resolved only at runtime.

Could you explain a bit this kind of behaviours and confirm my guessings? It is hard to come back from c# to c++ :D.

Cheers.

Comment: `IB` does not derive from `A`, so the compiler has no basis to permit direct casting from an `IB *` to an `A *`.   Hence the need to cast to a `C *` first (C does have `A` as a base, so a `C *` can be cast to an `A *`.   C# only supports multiple inheritance of interface, and you are assuming C++ multiple inheritance (which works with classes, unlike C#) is no different.

Comment: "This makes polimorphism useless"  - no, polymorphism uses `dynamic_cast` so your tests with static_cast are irrelevant

Comment: `dynamic_cast` means: "look at the vtables, see if we are a base class of some other object etc. etc." .  `static_cast` is a compile-time pointer adjustment .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be trying to write C# in C++ in which case I suggest just sticking with C#. However I'll try to answer your questions:

1) (note this is implementation details that are probably right on most systems) In a multiply inherited derived class typically an implementation will have multiple virtual tables as the first items in the object memory. In this case a `C` would have first an `A` vtable and then an `IB` vtable. If you try to use the derived pointer as `IB` without changing its address, the `IB` would be using the `A` class's vtable resulting in havoc. Thus, the compiler fixes up the address for you.

2) This is just the way the language tells us `static_cast` will work: converting between parent/child objects, and a few other relationships like different integral types. `dynamic_cast` is needed to traverse sibling relationships directly.

3) Correct, since `dynamic_cast` offers more flexibility for polymorphic conversions you can use it to convert between a sibling relationship.

I should make a closing remark that using multiple inheritance in C++ to provide an implementation to an interface is not a common pattern. There may be alternate approaches if you ask your real question.

Comment: I'm really interested in your closing remark. Would you mind showing or pointing me to the "more common" patterns?

Answer (score 1):

A static_cast requires there to be a single compile time relationship between the types that is more direct than any other relationship.

Imagine you had also defined 
`class D : public IB, public A`
The relationship between `A` and `IB` through `D` would be no more nor less direct than through `C`.  A static_cast can use the fact that the most direct relationship between `IB` and `C` is `IB` as a base class of `C` and can use the fact that the most direct relationship between `C` and `A` is `A` as a base class of `C`.  But the relationship between `IB` and `A` through `C` cannot be know to be the most direct compile time relationship, so static_cast can't use it (by dynamic_cast can use it as the only available run time relationship).